# React Native: Issue with AsyncStorage - Unable to Retrieve Stored Data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently working on a React Native project and encountering an issue with AsyncStorage. I am trying to store and retrieve data using AsyncStorage, but unfortunately, I'm unable to retrieve the stored data. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    storeData();
    retrieveData();
  }, []);

  const storeData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('myKey', 'Hello, Stack Overflow!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error storing data:', error);
    }
  };

  const retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey');
      console.log('Retrieved data:', data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving data:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Check the console for AsyncStorage logs</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Despite successfully storing data, the retrieveData function doesn't seem to be retrieving it. I've checked the key name, used console.log to debug, but I'm not seeing any errors.

Can someone please guide me on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue with AsyncStorage? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is printed on the console?

Comment: Please mark the question as solved if the answer is the one yu were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In you useEffect your 2 functions are called at the same timeand you're not using the `await` keyword

```
useEffect(() => {
    setAndRetrieve()
}, [])

async function setAndRetrieve() {
    await storeData();
    await retrieveData();
}
```